# How to change selected index in JComboBox when refreshing panel?

Tags: java, swing, panel, reload, jcombobox

I am making a simple sudoku and when I want to start a new game, I reload the panel. I first remove it and then add it to the frame. The problem is that I can choose the difficulty for new game, but it always selects the first "Easy" dificulty, not selected. So if I change it in JComboBox to "medium", when page is reloaded it will load the game with "Easy", not "medium".
What should I do so my refreshed panel will accept changed difficulty?

Here are methods that are used for this in my program:

```
JComboBox difficulty = new JComboBox();
DefaultComboBoxModel difficultyModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
difficultyModel.addElement("Easy");
difficultyModel.addElement("Medium");
difficultyModel.addElement("Hard");
difficulty.setModel(tezavnostModel);
difficulty.setSelectedIndex(0); 
difficulty.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));

newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            mainFrame.reloadSudokuBoard();
            sudokuBoard.pickDifficulty(getDifficulty()));
        }
    });

public String getDifficulty() {
    return (String)difficulty.getSelectedItem();
}

public void board(int[][] numbers, int zeros) {
    int numberZeros = setDifficulty(sudokuForm.getDifficulty());
    int[][] boardNumbers = gameNumbers();

public void reloadSudokuBoard() {
    String newDifficulty = (sudokuForm.getDifficulty());
    remove(sudokuBoard);
    sudokuBoard.board(sudokuBoard.gameNumbers(), sudokuBoard.setDifficulty(newDifficulty ));
    add(sudokuBoard, BorderLayout.WEST);
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(sudokuBoard);
}
```

Comment: 1) *I first remove it and then add it to the frame.*  - don't remove/add components. Just add a "Clear" function to your class the clears the text from all the components. 2) `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(sudokuBoard);` - you should NOT be invoking that method. That method is invoked when you change the LAF. Removing/adding components is not changing the LAF. If you ever do need to dynamically add/remove components from a panel, then you should invoke `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the panel.

Comment: @camickr I tried just removing it and adding it back, but it doesnt happen anything. If I add updateComponentTreeUI then it reloads the panel. I looked at everything, but cant figure it out... :(

Comment: Not sure why you replied to my comment. I made two suggestions and you ignored them both.

Comment: Because I tried what you suggested and it doesnt work. I have it in my code commented,  but I didnt post it here because I didnt think it matters.

Comment: My suggestion was to add a "Clear" function to your class so you are not removing/adding components. The second part was not a suggestion to fix this problem, it was for future when you actually do an a requirement that requires you to add components dynamically.

Comment: post [mre] please

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
    public void reloadSudokuBoard() {
    int index = difficulty.getSelectedIndex();
    String newDifficulty = (sudokuForm.getDifficulty());
    remove(sudokuBoard);
    sudokuBoard.board(sudokuBoard.gameNumbers(), sudokuBoard.setDifficulty(newDifficulty ));
    add(sudokuBoard, BorderLayout.WEST);
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(sudokuBoard);
    difficulty.setSelectedIndex(index);
}
```

Before removing components, you can use the `getSelectedIndex` to get the index that was selected. After the element have been added, the `setSelectedIndex` will fix it